# How to generate a valid access token programmatically for accessing wso2 apimanager gateway

Tags: wso2, token

I need a method to get access token for accessing api (via the apimanager 1.3.0 gateway) programmatically instead of using the apiman store app.

I followed the instruction in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Subscribing+to+an+API 
case Using the API Manager login API

But I always get Access failure for API

Please note that: Using the API Manager console in http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Subscribing+to+an+API works perfectly but I need a way to do the same function from an'application.

ERROR: you get an authorization error:

Access failure for API